# Can I mention in my CV a legislative bill that I wrote, but which is also not yet approved or deliberated upon by congress?

Tags: publications, funding, authorship, cv

I'm applying for a doctoral scholarship, and the scholarships office told me to mention in my CV all my academic and professional research publications/authored works.

Now, I once worked with a government agency where I wrote a bill that aimed to strengthen that agency. The plan was to submit the bill to congress in 2020 for sponsorship and approval. Due to the pandemic and other administrative challenges, however, this agency has not yet done so.

Can I still include this bill in my list of authored works? Thanks!

Comment: Certainly for something like public policy, experience with government is good. If the bill was never submitted (does not appear in the official record), I would specifically mention it with that work experience entry.

Answer (score 3):

If the work is published then you can treat it like any other. But for most purposes the form of the CV is up to you. You can include a special section with an appropriate label for such things. But you should probably also include the state of the "bill".

It is normal to have a section called "Work in Progress" for unfinished research, though this isn't exactly the same as that. But you can use a similar solution.